# Get cache line size of each installed GPU

Tags: c, gpu, multi-gpu

The C system libraries of common operating systems, such as Windows or Linux, give the ability to query the size of the processor's cache line size.

Is there any way to retrieve the same information, but for each available GPU?

I'm aware that this value is usually around 128 bytes, however I would like to know the exact value at run time.

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-3-0 makes it look like it is always 128?

Comment: AMD moved from 64 (RDNA1) to 128 (RDNA2). ARC is a bit new to the story. You probably won't get a GPU-independent answer, but that's probably pointless anyway. What kind of code could care? If you use the GPU for graphics, it's not your problem, and if you use if for computation (GPGPU), you use a vendor-specific library like CUDA.